# Is there a "Sync Locally?" option in the Android app of Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, android

as Ubuntu One under Ubuntu offers the "sync locally" option, I was looking for this very option inside of the Ubuntu One android app, but unfortunately I did not find it. So all my folders are synced into the cloud, but no file is available for offline use as the option is missing. Ticking every single file to download them is not a appropriate solution, because it takes long times to "sync" 100+ files manually. Besides of that changes have to be "resynced" manually as well. To cut a long story shot: Where is the "sync locally" option in this app? And supposingly there isn't such an option: what is your workaround for this?

Greetz
rodgerwilco

Answer (score 3):

There is no "sync locally" or "sync folder" option on the android UbuntuOne Files app. Should be a high priority feature add, in my book. UbuntuOne does the automatic photo upload quite well. It just needs a way to do the same for other user-selected SDCARD folders.  Seems silly that you have to add files individually rather than entire folders, like you can with UbuntuOne on Linux/Ubuntu or various cloud storage apps for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The app FolderSync in the Android Market claims it can do it. Try it out: [marketlink](https://market.android.com/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiZGsudGFjaXQuYW5kcm9pZC5mb2xkZXJzeW5jLmxpdGUiXQ..)

Comment: The OP asks about Ubuntu One, not a different client.

Answer (score 1):

You can long-press on a folder to download all files inside it: you do not have to download each one individually. This does not keep those files in sync (that is: further changes to those files in the cloud need to be manually downloaded again) but it's a lot quicker than downloading each file individually.